# Option selection and return specific object

Tags: php

I have two different methods that output tweets but from two different sources.

```
$tweets = Twitter::get_tweets();
$lists = Twitter::get_user_first_list_tweets();
```

Both return objects that can be accessed using `->data` for an array of tweets.

So I have `$tweets_option = get_field('show_tweets_for');` which outputs either `profile` or `list`.

Then I have a loop that goes through:

```
<?php if ($tweets): ?>
   <?php foreach ($tweets->data as $tweet): ?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What's the best way for me to define it like this:

- By default, 'profile' is selected on `$tweets_option`, which I want to output `$tweets = Twitter::get_tweets();`.
- Let's say someone selects 'list' from `$tweets_option`, how can I set `$lists` to equal `$tweets` so that it still runs through the tweets?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$tweets_option = get_field('show_tweets_for'); 

$tweets =  $tweets_option == 'profile' ? Twitter::get_tweets() : Twitter::get_user_first_list_tweets();
```

Comment: @user17997251 - in case it wasn't clear, THEODORE is suggesting that you try a PHP [ternary operator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-ternary-operator/), essentially doing an "if/then'else" assignment to "$tweets": its value will be either "Twitter::get_tweets()" or "Twitter::get_user_first_list_tweets()".